# how to properly use intent? Android beginner

Tags: android

I am a beginner in android and I am trying to learn how to use intent.
In my code, I am trying to send 2 integers to a different activity and perform some calculation and return back in the Main activity with the answer.

This is my main activity and with a click of a button it should send 10, 50 to my calculate class and from there I will click operator buttons like add, multiply, divide and send back the answer here in main activity.

So far I am able to received these numbers to my Calculate class and perform operation there but I am not sure how to get back here in main activity with the answers.

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if(getIntent() != null){

        String msg = getIntent().getStringExtra("MSG");
        int result = getIntent().getIntExtra("result", 0);
        Toast.makeText(this, "" + msg + result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
   }

public void onClick(View v){
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Calculate.class);

   i.putExtra("MSG", "Receive two numbers : ");
   i.putExtra("second", 10);
   i.putExtra("first", 50);
   startActivity(i);

   }
}
```

Calculate class

```
public class Calculate extends Activity{

private int calc;
private int first;
private int second;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    Intent i = getIntent();

    if(getIntent() != null){
        String msg = i.getStringExtra("MSG");
        first = i.getIntExtra("first", 0);
        second = i.getIntExtra("second", 0);
        Toast.makeText(this, "" + msg + first + " and " + second,    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

public void add(View v){
    calc = first + second;
    Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("MSG", "Answer");
    i.putExtra("result",calc);

 }
}
```

Comment: are u going to show answer in main activity?

Comment: after the startactivity in the class, type finish(); then similarly pass intents from the calcuate class, to fetch it in the main activity, check if intent contains the value, if not it is the first time call, if yes, fetch particular value from the intent and populate the text box

Answer (score 2):

you can use startActivityForResult and onActivityResult methods. fist in main activity you call startActivityForResult that means you want to get result from secondActivity (Calculate activity) and then override onActivityResult in main activity to get result.

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if(getIntent() != null){

        String msg = getIntent().getStringExtra("MSG");
        int result = getIntent().getIntExtra("result", 0);
        Toast.makeText(this, "" + msg + result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
   }

public void onClick(View v){
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Calculate.class);

   i.putExtra("MSG", "Receive two numbers : ");
   i.putExtra("second", 10);
   i.putExtra("first", 50);
   startActivityForResult(i, 1);

   }
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            String result=data.getStringExtra("result");
        }
        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            //Write your code if there's no result
        }
    }
}//onActivityResult
}



public class Calculate extends Activity{

private int calc;
private int first;
private int second;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    Intent i = getIntent();

    if(getIntent() != null){
        String msg = i.getStringExtra("MSG");
        first = i.getIntExtra("first", 0);
        second = i.getIntExtra("second", 0);
        Toast.makeText(this, "" + msg + first + " and " + second,    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

public void add(View v){
   calc = first + second;
   Intent returnIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
   returnIntent.putExtra("result",calc );
    setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
    finish();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Calculate extends Activity{

private int calc;
private int first;
private int second;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    Intent i = getIntent();

    if(getIntent() != null){
        String msg = i.getStringExtra("MSG");
        first = i.getIntExtra("first", 0);
        second = i.getIntExtra("second", 0);
        Toast.makeText(this, "" + msg + first + " and " + second,    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

public void add(View v){
    calc = first + second;
    Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("MSG", "Answer");
    i.putExtra("result",calc);
    startActivity(i);
 }
}
```

You need a `startActivity(i);` in `add()` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by

> onActivityResult()

method of android intent.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(data.getExtras().containsKey("widthInfo")){
        width.setText(data.getStringExtra("widthInfo"));
        }
    if(data.getExtras().containsKey("heightInfo")){
            height.setText(data.getStringExtra("heightInfo"));
    }
}
```

See these links for more info:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/CheckActivityresultandonActivityResult.htm

http://www.mybringback.com/android-sdk/12204/onactivityresult-android-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you should be using `startActivityForResult()` here.

So, in your MainActivity, your `onClick()` would be modified to call `startActivityForResult()`:

```
public void onClick(View v){
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Calculate.class);

    i.putExtra("MSG", "Receive two numbers : ");
    i.putExtra("second", 10);
    i.putExtra("first", 50);
    startActivityForResult(i, 100); //modified
}
```

Then in MainActivity, you would also add `onActivityResult` to get the result:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 100 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

        String msg = data.getStringExtra("MSG");
        int result = data.getIntExtra("result", 0);
        Toast.makeText(this, "" + msg + result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

Then, in the `Calculate` Activity, you would calculate the result, and send it back to `MainActivity` in an Intent, which will send the the `MSG` and `result` to `onActivityResult()` in MainActivity:

```
public void add(View v){
    calc = first + second;

    Intent i = new Intent(); //modified
    i.putExtra("MSG", "Answer");
    i.putExtra("result",calc);
    setResult(RESULT_OK,i); //added
    finish(); //added
}
```

Note that the reason it would be better for you to use `startActivityForResult()` here is that it would prevent having to add multiple Activities onto the back stack.

Say for example, you do two calculations (two trips from MainActivity to Calculate and back).
If you just used `startActivity()`, your back stack would then look like this:

```
MainActivity->Calculate->MainActivity->Calculate->MainActivity
```

And, it would just keep growing the more calculations you do.

Using `startActivityForResult()`, you are always just adding an instance of `Calculate` to the back stack, and then popping it and returning to the same instance of `MainActivity`.  So, your back stack would always be just:

```
MainActivity
```

or...

```
MainActivity->Calculate
```

depending on which Activity you are currently in.  As you can see, this is a huge improvement over the first option, which just keeps growing as you do more calculations.